# How does Shotwell detect duplicates?

Tags: shotwell, photo-management

Couldn't find any answers to this with google. When importing the same folder of pictures twice, Shotwell will skip duplicate photos. But how does it detect duplicates? If I import two different folders of pictures, some of which have the same name for some reason, will Shotwell assume they are duplicates? Or does it also factor in the file size, making false duplicates unlikely? Or does it hash the pictures, making false duplicates all but impossible?

Comment: @Tim Nope, seems to be automatic :S ([the NerdAnswer link](http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=658518))

Comment: @Tim Seems so, I've never heard of NerdAnswer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe it is more advanced than simple names, I just tried. In fact it would seem that it doesn't base it on name at all.

So I just created the following:

```
TestDir
  │
  ├─ blue.png #Blue A4 page
  ├─ blue2.png #Blue A4 page
  ├─ green.png #Blue A4 page
  ├─ red.png #Yellow A4 page
  ├─ yellow.png #Yellow A4 page
  ├─ yellow2.png #Yellow A4 page
  └ TestDir2
       │
       ├─ yellow.png #Blue A4 page
       └─ yellow.png #Blue A4 page
```

Imported the folder TestDir (which imports from any subdirectories too). This was the notice:

```
6 duplicate photos were not imported:
/home/tim/Pictures/Test/red.png
/home/tim/Pictures/Test/yellow2.png
/home/tim/Pictures/Test/green.png
/home/tim/Pictures/Test/blue2.png
(and 2 more)

2 photos successfully imported.
```

The two it had imported were blue.png and yellow.png. This is because they were created first (it chooses the oldest if there are duplicates).

This was confirmed by the next test:

```
TestDir
  │
  ├─ blue.png #Blue A4 page
  ├─ blue2.png #Blue A4 page
  ├─ green.png #Blue A4 page (sorry OCD people)
  ├─ red.png #Yellow A4 page (sorry OCD people)
  ├─ yellow.png #Yellow A4 page
  ├─ yellow2.png #Yellow A4 page
  ├─ pink2.png #Pink A4 page 
  ├─ pink.png #Pink A4 page
  └ TestDir2
       │
       ├─ yellow.png #Blue A4 page
       └─ yellow.png #Blue A4 page
```

`pink2.png` and `pink.png` have been created. `pink2.png` was created first, then `pink.png`

```
8 duplicate photos were not imported:
/home/tim/Pictures/Test/red.png
/home/tim/Pictures/Test/yellow2.png
/home/tim/Pictures/Test/green.png
/home/tim/Pictures/Test/blue2.png
(and 4 more)

3 photos successfully imported.
```

The successful imported ones were `blue.png`,`yellow.png` and `pink2.png`.

Because of that I assume it uses a hashing algorithm.

It is accurate enough that changing just 1 pixel of colour from green to yellow on an A4 page caused it to not detect as a duplicate. Pretty accurate then!

In fact, I just found this post [here](http://shotwell.996238.n3.nabble.com/Getting-rid-of-duplicates-td26155.html):

> Once this bug is fixed, Shotwell  will use (exclusively) a full MD5
>   hash of the file to perform duplicate  checking, which is a pretty
>   darn accurate way to find duplicates.

In fact in the [source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/shotwell/tree/src/BatchImport.vala), at line 732 is this: <sup><sub>[Kudos @ Jeremie Miserez](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509133/how-does-shotwell-detect-duplicates/509141?noredirect=1#comment687726_509141)</sub></sup>

```
imported_full_md5_table.has_key(prepared_file.full_md5)) {
```

Sounds like it uses a MD5 hash!

<sub>[Shapes for directory tree from here](http://web.archive.org/web/20151024163958/http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/unicode/unidata25.html)</sub>

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: You can also see the logic in the source code here (line 732): https://git.gnome.org/browse/shotwell/tree/src/BatchImport.vala.