# Some tools for managing photos

Tags: 14.04, photo-management, photo

I have a lot of photos in different folders. Some of them are copies of each other. I want to put those photos in one folder and I want a tool to identify the duplicate files.

I also want some photo managers.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

The first tool that comes to mind is **digiKam**. Here are some features mentioned on their site ([link](https://www.digikam.org/about?q=about/features)):

- import pictures
- organize your collection
- view items
- edit and enhance
- create (slideshows, calendar, print, ...)
- share your creations (using
  social web services, email, your own web allery, ...)

The ony possible issue is that it's part of KDE environment, so it may bring a lot of kde dependencies.

Another good tool is **Darktable** ([link](http://www.darktable.org)). It's description from their site:

> darktable is an open source photography workflow application and RAW
>   developer. A virtual lighttable and darkroom for photographers. It
>   manages your digital negatives in a database, lets you view them
>   through a zoomable lighttable and enables you to develop raw images
>   and enhance them.

Comment: But how can I find photos that are the same.

Comment: digiKam has Find duplicates tool: [link](https://www.digikam.org/node/333)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **[Shotwell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell)** also has an automatic duplicated detection on the Import.

> **FileImportJob** -- Duplicate detection occurs in the main thread by
>   searching the database for photos with the same MD5 as the file. If no
>   duplicates are found, a FileImportJob is fired off. This job copies
>   the file into the library (generally ~/Pictures) if necessary or
>   requested by the user. A PhotoFileInterrogator object sniffs out the
>   file’s contents to determine various relevant information, such as the
>   photo’s dimensions, colorspace, etc. That information is used to
>   prepare a data structure for adding to the database. Thumbnails are
>   also generated during this stage.
>
> If all has gone well up to this point, the file is formally imported
>   into the database. Because the thumbnail cache needs a database ID to
>   store its thumbnails, writing the thumbnails has to be delayed until
>   this point.

Source: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell/Architecture/Importing#ImportQueuePage

Check also "[How does Shotwell detect duplicates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509133/how-does-shotwell-detect-duplicates)" for more details.